# Installing kubesec on mac 01 M1

Tags: macos, kubernetes

hello i am getting this error when installing kubesec by shyiko
followed this [guide][1]
I am installing the kubesec binary in my m1 and it fails . please assist

`brew install shyiko/kubesec/kubesec`

```
=> Installing kubesec from shyiko/kubesec
==> Installing dependencies for shyiko/kubesec/kubesec: go
==> Installing shyiko/kubesec/kubesec dependency: go
==> Pouring go--1.19.1.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19.1: 12,436 files, 629.0MB
==> Installing shyiko/kubesec/kubesec
==> make fetch
Last 15 lines from /Users/user/Library/Logs/Homebrew/kubesec/01.make:

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
go get \
        github.com/mitchellh/gox \
        github.com/Masterminds/glide \
        github.com/modocache/gover \
        github.com/aktau/github-release && \
        glide install
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
        'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
        To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
        like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
        For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
        or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.
make: *** [fetch] Error 1

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


  [1]: https://github.com/shyiko/kubesec
```

Answer (score 1):

i managed to fix this

macOS

```
curl -sSL https://github.com/willyguggenheim/kubesec/releases/download/0.9.2/kubesec-0.9.2-darwin-amd64 \
  -o kubesec && chmod a+x kubesec && sudo mv kubesec /usr/local/bin/
```

Verify PGP signature (optional but recommended):

```
curl -sSL https://github.com/willyguggenheim/kubesec/releases/download/0.9.2/kubesec-0.9.2-darwin-amd64.asc \
  -o kubesec.asc
curl -sS https://keybase.io/shyiko/pgp_keys.asc | gpg --import
gpg --verify kubesec.asc /usr/local/bin/kubesec
```

on Monterey

```
GO111MODULE="on" go install github.com/willyguggenheim/kubesec@latest
chmod a+x $GOPATH/bin/kubesec
mv $GOPATH/bin/kubesec /usr/local/bin/
```